# Is Windows process Running, Java differentWindows OS on Different Lanaguages

Tags: java, windows-7, windows-xp, windows-2000

I am using Java in programing and want to watch after some processes if running or not.
I have to make my implementation platform indepenant; support different OS (Windows XP,7 & 2000) also this OS in different lanaguages (French, English, Japaness, Chiness, Arabic , RTL etc ...)

I tried first to use command line, but I was faced with a problem that the command reply is in the OS language so it replies in French if OS is french and in English if English.

I used the command in different way, but was faced with another problem which is encoding, so I have to set the encoding to UTS8 before calling the command, this worked will with English & French but I doubt it will work with Chiness & RTL languages.

Do you have any clue for a better Solution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no universally accepted way for doing this because all operating systems are very different. The two [approaches](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html) we have available are probably the best. If you run into language problems with *tasklist* perhaps you should then take a look at the vbs version. The upside in that is that it should work independently of the language and Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Java in programing and want
>   to watch after some processes if
>   running or not.

Frankly, this is a problem that is difficult to solve in Java. Java is meant to be cross-platform, hence it isolates you from platform-specific features. Therefore there is no "official" way to get a list of running processes in Java. There are some hacks (such as invoking "tasklist", as explained by erloewe), but no real solution.

Your best bet is probably to write a program in some other language (e.g. C, Perl or VBScript), and invoke it from Java.